# What command do you use to preview any image

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a command in sh using the software ImageMagick. I was trying to find a command that allows me use any image( presumably jpeg) and be able to preview the image but at a 200x200 pixels instead of the original size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display -size 200x200 filename`

See http://www.imagemagick.org/www/display.html

Answer (score 1):

I use `xv` or `xview`:

```
xv -geom 200x200 filename
xview -geometry 200x200 filename
```